# Why can't round bracket be correctly regarded as a constructor calling?

Tags: c++, constructor, definition

I wrote a `move` to imitate `std::move`, and try to use a new struct `Foo` to test it. However, something wrong happened.

```sh
.\main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
.\main.cpp:46:7: error: conflicting declaration 'Foo x'
   46 |   Foo(x);
      |       ^
.\main.cpp:43:15: note: previous declaration as 'std::string x'
   43 |   std::string x = "123";
      |               ^
```

I replace the code `Foo(x)` with `Foo foo = Foo(x)`, then everything went just fine.
I'm using `MinGW32 g++ 9.2.0`, compiling with command `g++ main.cpp -std=c++14`

See the code below for more detail:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
struct Remove_Reference {
  typedef T type;
};

template <class T>
struct Remove_Reference<T&> {
  typedef T type;
};

template <class T>
struct Remove_Reference<T&&> {
  typedef T type;
};

template <typename T>
constexpr typename Remove_Reference<T>::type&& move(T&& x) noexcept {
  return static_cast<typename Remove_Reference<T>::type&&>(x);
}

struct Foo {
  Foo() {}
  Foo(std::string&& foo) : val(foo) {
    std::cout << "rvalue reference initialize" << std::endl;
  }
  Foo(const std::string& foo) : val(::move(foo)) {
    std::cout << "const lvalue reference initialize" << std::endl;
  }
  std::string val;
};

void call(std::string&& x) {
  std::cout << "rvalue reference: " << x << std::endl;
}

void call(const std::string& x) {
  std::cout << "const lvalue reference: " << x << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  std::string x = "123";

  Foo{x};
  // Foo(x);

  Foo{::move(x)};
  Foo(::move(x));

  call(x);
  call(::move(x));

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What would you expect `Foo{x};` should do? Create an anonymous temporary?

Comment: @DanielLangr Yes

Comment: Sorry, should have been `Foo(x);` in my previous comment. Here is also the relevant part of the standard: http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.ambig. Anyway, you can write `Foo(x).val;` instead.

Comment: You may want to look up "most vexing parse".

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. It's a good think to look up, but there's no vexing parse with `Foo(x);`. It *can't* be a function declaration.

Comment: @cigien It's a simplified version of the same thing, declaration/expression ambiguity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This statement:

```
Foo(x);
```

is not a function call, or a constructor call. It's just a declaration, that says `x` is of type `Foo`. The parentheses are optional around the declarator `x`, so it's equivalent to:

```
Foo x;
```

This of course gives an error, since you already have a `std::string` named `x`, and you can't give the same name to multiple entities in the same scope.

---

Note that the *expression*:

```
Foo(x)
```

is different than the *statement* above (with the `;`). This expression can mean different things depending on the context it is used in.

---

For example, this code:

```
Foo foo = Foo(x);
```

is perfectly fine. This does copy initialization of a variable named `foo`, from the expression `Foo(x)`, which is a temporary `Foo` constructed from the argument `x`. (It's not particularly important here, but from c++17, there's no temporary on the right hand side; the object just gets constructed in place).

Comment: Why? is this a part of ambiguity?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. There's no ambiguity here, it's just that `Foo x;` `Foo (x);`, `Foo ((x));` are all equivalent in c++.

Comment: Can't `Foo foo = Foo(x)` be regarded as calling `Foo(x)`, then assigned to `Foo foo`?

Comment: @cigien Actually, there seemingly is: http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.ambig.

Comment: Yes, you can think of it like that, and it will suffice. It's just that from c++17, there's *technically* mo temporary.

Comment: @DanielLangr Sorry, I don't follow. That page says there is an ambiguity only if it *could* be parsed as a declaration. But `T(a)` can't, so it's unambiguous.

Comment: @cigien Me neither. Didn't you write in your answer that `Foo(x);` was a declaration? But it can be parsed as an expression-statement as well.

Comment: @DanielLangr Oh, I see what you mean now. Edited the answer to be clearer. Thanks for pointing that out.